# Flutter position Carousel Slider not centered

Tags: list, flutter, dart, constraints, carousel

I am using [CarouselSlider](https://pub.dev/packages/carousel_slider) in my app and right now it looks like this:

[image]

The problem is that I don't want the highlighted/selected widget in the middle but on the right. Like this:

[image]

So what I need to do is, moving the whole widget to the right so the right half of the list is out of the view and only the left halt is being displayed. But I have no idea how I can achieve this...

This is my code:

```
    @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      child: Container(
        height: 50,
        child: CarouselSlider.builder(
            itemCount: data.length,
            itemBuilder:
                (BuildContext context, int itemIndex, int pageViewIndex) =>
                    _buildListItem(itemIndex),
            options: CarouselOptions(
              viewportFraction: 0.35,
              reverse: true,
              enlargeCenterPage: true,
              onPageChanged: (index, whatever) {
                print(index);
              },
              enableInfiniteScroll: false,
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            )),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildListItem(int index) {
    return Container(
      color: AppColors.red,
      height: 50,
      width: 100,
      child: Center(
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.scaled),
          child: Text(
            data[index].toString(),
            style: AppTextStyles.glossAndBloomH2Regular,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

And this is where I call it:

```
Positioned(
                  right: sidePadding,
                  bottom: 30,
                  left: sidePadding,
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                    children: [
                      IconButtonWithExpandedTouchTarget(
                        onTapped: () {
                          showModalBottomSheet(
                            context: context,
                            backgroundColor: AppColors.transparent,
                            builder: (BuildContext context) {
                              return ModalBottomSheetView();
                            },
                          );
                        },
                        svgPath: 'assets/icons/menue.svg',
                      ),
                      YearSlider(),
                    ],
                  ),
```

Every help is appreciated! Let me know if you need anything more

Comment: Can you add more of this parent including data.

Comment: @YeasinSheikh yes, added it

Comment: To align right, it might not be possible with `CarouselSlider`, if you consider creating custom, then you can algin it.